# Getting not correct data from API Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, mongoose

I hope I didn't repeat this question, but i didn't find any on stackoverflow.

this is a login method, i send a 200 status code with the user object as a response when someone login correctly,
but on the client side i only get the default response of 200, and when I login with the wrong password I get 500 default response with no any data of what I send! no error messages and no objects when I sign-in correctly.

this is the middleware

i use

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

the login method

```
exports.logIn =async (req,res)=>{

 let {email,password} = req.body;
 let user;
 let passwordCorrect;
 try{
   user = await UserModel.findOne({email:email});

   if(user){
       console.log("user found")
     passwordCorrect= await bcryptjs.compare(password,user.password);

     if(passwordCorrect){
       console.log("password correct")

       res.json({user:user})
     }else{
       console.log("password not")

       throw new Error("password is wrong");

     }

   }else{
     console.log("user not found ")

     throw new Error("This user is not in our system");
   }

 }catch(err){
   console.log("catched error  ")
   console.log(err)

   res.status(500).json({
     status:'fail',
     message:err.message
   })

 }

}
```

and this is the response i get when i login correctly, 
the response is missing the data that am sending from server,
and incase of wrong password , i recive 500 without the error message that i send from server

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/login", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/login"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

from client side where i use react

```
  try{

            const user  = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/user/login",{
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                },
                method:"POST",
                body:JSON.stringify(data)
            });

              if(user.ok){
               // auth.login();
               console.log('ok')
               console.log(user)
            }else{
                console.log('not ok')

                console.log(user)

                setError(user.message)
            }

         }catch(err){

            console.log("error ")
            console.log(err);
            setError(err)

 }
```

and this is the middleware to accept requests from another domains

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header("Accses-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,DELETE,PATCH");
console.log(req.body);
    next();
  });
```

Comment: Can you have an example of how you send the request and the response you are receiving ?

Comment: Yes , i will edit my question

Comment: Please use return while you are returning your response in both the case 
1. Success Response
2. Error Response

Comment: have you tried ` next(err)` inside you catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) returns a promise containing the response. This is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the `json()` method.

So your code should be:

```js
try {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/user/login", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    console.log("ok");
    let user = await response.json();
    console.log("user: ", user);
  } else {
    console.log("not ok");
    console.log(response);
    setError(response.message);
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log("error ");
  console.log(err);
  setError(err);
}
```